# Finding function calls using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to detect functions between call-chains.

For example, I can use

```
re.search("([\w_]+)\((|[\W\d\w\,]+)\)", line)
```

to find

```
print(len("AA"))
```

but it is reasonably not compatible with code like:

```
print(i + len("AA") + j + len("BBB"))
```

Help me.

Comment: Do you want to *parse* Python code?

Comment: first, it's not a good idea to parse nested function calls with regex, since the language is not regular. second, you can use the ast modul to analyse python code

Comment: Maybe a profiler would help here to see a caller graph, e.g.: `pydoc -k profile`. BTW: "Help me." sounds a bit rude, "Please help me." would be more polite, but both are not needed here at SX.

Answer (score 1):

Your needs may be better served by the `ast` module:

```
import ast

a = ast.parse('print(i + len("AA") + j + len("BBB"))')
print ast.dump(a)

>>>
Module(body=[Print(dest=None, values=[BinOp(left=BinOp(left=BinOp(left=Name(id='i',
ctx=Load()), op=Add(), right=Call(func=Name(id='len', ctx=Load()), args=[Str(s='AA')], 
keywords=[], starargs=None, kwargs=None)), op=Add(), right=Name(id='j', ctx=Load())), 
op=Add(), right=Call(func=Name(id='len', ctx=Load()), args=[Str(s='BBB')], keywords=[], 
starargs=None, kwargs=None))], nl=True)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
(\w+)\(((?:[^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*)\)
```

This captures the name of the function in group 1, and the contents the brackets (the parameters) in group 2.

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/NrRywwrhKw) of this regex working with your examples.

---

BTW, Your regex could use some attention:

- `[\w_]+` is equivalent to just `\w+` because `\w` includes underscore
- `[\W\d\w\,]` is equivalent to just `.`, because the combination `\W\w` (everything not a word char and every word char) includes everything